# Many “postgres.exe” processes on Windows. Is there a way to close unused “postgres.exe” process. It only increases

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

My Postgres 9.4 runs on Windows, and it creates many “postgres.exe” processes. Is there a way to close unused “postgres.exe” processes? It only increases.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Close your connections. Every open connection is one process.

Comment: The problem is it takes a long time to close after the connection is no longer used

Comment: The process will go away  immediately after a connection was closed. There are however about 8 processes that will always be there independent of the number of connections.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply!